# PHP Sort results from key values inside multiple json files

Tags: php, json

is it possible to sort the results by key value inside separate json files?
I need to sort the result by "id" value.
Sorry if this is a duplicate but I've searched entire internet and couldn't find a solution.

Many thanks for your help.

```
<div class="container grid grid-cols-2 gap-6 tablet:grid-cols-3 desktop:grid-cols-6">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    $dir = (new DirectoryIterator(__DATA_PAGES_PATH__ . 'products/content/' . $lang));
    foreach ($dir as $productsdata) {
        if ($productsdata->isDot()) continue;
        $productdata = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DATA_PAGES_PATH__ . 'products/content/' . $lang . "/" . $productsdata));
        if ($productdata->popular > 0) {
    ?>
            <?php echo $productdata->id ?>
    <?php
        };
        if (++$i == 6) break;
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Content of multiple json files inside the directory:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "prd-name-0",
    "category": "prd-category-0"
}
```

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "prd-name-1",
    "category": "prd-category-1"
}
```

Comment: Not if you output the content from each single file directly. You would need to put all this data into an array first, then you sort that array, and then you loop over the sorted array to create the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was my solution for anyone who might need this. thanks to @CBroe

```
function sortkey($folder, $key)
{
    $GLOBALS['files'] = glob(__data__ . $folder . '/' . $GLOBALS['lang'] . '/*.json');
    $GLOBALS['sort'] = [];
    foreach ($GLOBALS['files'] as $GLOBALS['file']) {
        $GLOBALS['thisData'] = file_get_contents($GLOBALS['file']);
        $GLOBALS['thisDataArr'] = json_decode($GLOBALS['thisData']);
        if (isset($GLOBALS['thisDataArr']->$key)) {
            $GLOBALS['sort'][$GLOBALS['thisDataArr']->$key] = basename(str_replace('.json', '', $GLOBALS['file']));
        }
    }
    ksort($GLOBALS['sort']);
    // var_dump($GLOBALS['sort']);
}
```